# Количество копий DataContext для сайта.

Tags: linq2sql, c#, .net

Стоит ли создавать при каждом обращении User-а на сайт объект DataContext, что бы брать некую информацию из БД? Или его нужно сделать глобально созданным?

Comment: Уже обсуждался подобный [вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/40271/linq-to-sql-оптимизация-работы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобально созданный `DataContext` точно не нужно использовать, этот класс не потокобезопасен. Можно создавать экземпляр при каждом обращении, можно хранить его в переменых сессии. В варианте с сессией будут сложности с управлением временем жизни контекста.